# grep command cannot find words in certain files

Tags: command-line

let's imagine two files (among many others in a directory):

- `file1.doc` (with a text like `I'm happier today than I was yesterday` for example)
- `file2.doc` (with a sentence like `I'm very sad today`)

The `grep` command works like a charm and can find the word `today` (for example) in just a second, in `file1`. However, it's unable to find the word `sad` (for example) in `file2`. No way. No matter the word I search the command provides no output for `file2`. As though the file were empty.

Why does the command work in some files but not in others?
What can go wrong?

Comment: Are you sure these 2 files have same format? I can only suggest you to take care that your 2nd file isn't encrypted. Also, you can test to find a common word these to file using `grep -r today`

Comment: Try `grep -i sad *.doc`

Comment: Just a question (for clarification): Are these files actual Microsoft Word files that contain the mentioned sentences when you open them with Word? Or are these simply plain text files which just happen to use the extension `.doc`? In the first case, `grep` can't work reliably, since it simply looks at the bytes that make up the file, but it does not interpret any rich text encodings, especially not proprietary ones like the format used by Word. If you need to grep for text in Word files, you should extract the text before grepping using appropriate tools, e.g., `catdoc file1.txt | grep sad`.

Comment: (I meant to write: `catdoc file1.doc | grep sad` of course.)

Comment: I'm almost sure it's a MS Word document. But I have another version of the same document in .ODT format and the grep command doesn't work either.

Comment: besides, the command "grep -i sad *.doc" doesn't work either. It's a really weird situation.

Comment: yes, I can extract the text the way you said, but what I'm trying to do is to find a word in a document (among many others) whose name I don't know. I cannot extract the text first, because I don't know in which document the word is!